# Cannot Create A Page or Post in WordPress 5.2.1

Tags: pages, block-editor

I am using the Gutenberg Editor, and when trying to create a new page to publish, I get: **Publishing Failed**.

Debugging using the console gives me:

```
 13?_locale=user
 Status: 403 (in red)
 Type: fetch
 Initiator: api-fetch.min.js?ver=3.1
```

Can someone help?

Comment: This isn't an error I've seen before. Can you please start by disabling all plugins and re-activating them one-by-one trying to publish every time? If it works without a specific plugin then you've found your culprit.

Comment: The only fix is to switch back to the classic editor. Then it instantly works. Disabling all plugins was one thing I did try, and that didn't help

Comment: It's literally impossbile that you can't create a new post or page without plugins on a fresh install of WP running a default theme. Something is in the way so switch back to twenty nineteen to try as well.